# Django canot locate my static files directory

Tags: django

**Hey Guys, 
I have a problem, django canot find my static files when testing the page. Google Console errors,**

*127.0.0.1/:10 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/all.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
and many other errors like that

**My static files in settings.py;**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_FILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'btre/static')
]
```

**my static files are properly, i mean double checked, in my project folder (i.e. btre/static/)
did collect static command in manage.py but still getting errors. 
I also properly referenced the CSS and JS files in base.html as well;**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.css' %}">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
  <!-- Lightbox -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/lightbox.min.css' %}">
  <!-- Custom -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How stupid of me.

```
STATIC_FILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'btre/static')
]
```

made an error above there. should have been like;

STATICFILES_DIRS instead of STATIC_FILES_DIRS

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be

> STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') ]

?

Comment: yea, but i make a subfolder of static in my project 'btre'.so, works for me.